ggiraph single point deselection is not dynamic
I am not sure if this is a bug.
library(shiny)
library(ggiraph)

ui <- 
fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Interactive ggiraph Plot"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("num", "Number of points:", 
                  min = 1, max = 100, value = 50)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      ggiraphOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- 
function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderggiraph({
    gg <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
      geom_point_interactive(aes(tooltip = Species, data_id = paste(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Species)), size = 3) +
      theme_minimal()
    ggiraph(ggobj = gg,  opts_selection(type = "multiple"))
  })

  observeEvent(input$plot_selected, {
                  print(input$plot_selected)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)

Reproducing:

select any single point -> see the observeEvent printing the selected point.
unselect that same point --> no reactivity is observed.

This is not the case if you select 2 points and then unselect one.
Thank you!

By default, observeEvent doesn't get triggered when the event expression evaluates to NULL. See the docs and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58292646/using-observeevent-in-shiny-with-null-values
